# Image height stretching in flexbox

Tags: html, image, css, flexbox

So I already researched this briefly. I put an img in a div and made the img width 100%, which should have an impact on the height. I'm not understanding what's going on here. I just need my images to remain to their proper aspect ratio in the following flexbox.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: stretch;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 80%;
  /*padding-top: 2%;
 padding-bottom: 18%;
    margin: 5% auto 8% auto; */
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
.top {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
.top * {
  1 1 50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  height: 100%;
}
.bottom {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: flex-start;
  border: 2px solid orange;
}
.top,
.bottom {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  height: 50%;
}
.topa {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: orange;
}
.topa div img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="bigwrap">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="top">
      <div class="topa">
        <div>
          <img src="http://placehold.it/209x205" width="209" height="205" alt="Picture of kid" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <img src="http://placehold.it/209x205" width="209" height="205" alt="Picture of kid" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="topb">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It would help if there were actual images in the code so we could see what the problem is. Please provide more details about what you currently have and how the layout should actually look.

Comment: I have updated your question so that placeholder images are used, but it is still unclear to me what you're intending to achieve. You're spuriously wrapping a lot of elements with flex display, and I believe that might not be necessary. Can you include a screenshot to show the intended layout?

Answer (score 0):

You are not using flexbox in the right way.
To do what you want `margin:auto` on `.topa` is enough...

Here is a [css-tricks article](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to explain very weel how flexbox works

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 80%;
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
.top {
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
.top * {
  height: 100%;
}
.bottom {
  border: 2px solid orange;
}
.topa {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: orange;
  margin: auto;
}
.topa div img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="bigwrap">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="top">
      <div class="topa">
        <div>
          <img src="http://placehold.it/209x205" width="209" height="205" alt="Picture of kid" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <img src="http://placehold.it/209x205" width="209" height="205" alt="Picture of kid" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="topb">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -3):

Use max-width for your image in CSS. And remove width?and height atribute from image tag. Or use  height property auto in your img tag and css is-

```
.topa div img {
    Max-width: 100%;
    Height:auto;
}
```